# JPA / JPQL query without resultSet nor update/delete count

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I wish to execute a (Postgre)SQL native query that is not a "SELECT" nor an "UPDATE" nor a "DELETE" query. It is "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name;" and has no result as far as I know.

What is the right way to execute such a query using JPA / JPQL ?

Execution methods on `javax.persistence.Query` seem to require a result set or an update/delete count.

Comment: Have you tried to create a native query and call executeUpdate()? Another idea could be to pack the call in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure from JPA

Comment: I had not yet since I was kept away from my keyboard. I can tell the result soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, `executeUpdate()` was the correct way to do the job.

```
final javax.persistence.EntityManager em;
em.createNativeQuery("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name;").executeUpdate();
```